# Prolog replace "+" with "-"

Tags: replace, prolog

I wish to write a predicate `invert(X, Y)`, that holds when `Y` is `X` but with every occurence of `+` replaced with `-`.

e.g.

```
?- invert(2 + 3, 2 - 3). 
yes.
```

e.g.

```
?- invert(3 + (2 + 4), X). 
X = 3 - (2 - 4).
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the univ `=..` to inspect the terms of your expression and replace the `+/2` operator with a `-/2` operator.

```
invert(Left+Right, ILeft-IRight):-
  !,
  invert(Left, ILeft),
  invert(Right, IRight).
invert(Exp, IExp):-
  Exp=..[Functor|Args],
  findall(NArg,
    ( member(Arg, Args),
      invert(Arg, NArg)
    ), NArgs),
  IExp=..[Functor|NArgs].
```

The first clause deals with the terms with principal functor +. The second clause applies to terms with different principal functor.

[edit]
As one of the comments suggest, you may change the first clause to avoid infinite loops when both arguments of `invert/2` are uninstantiated, just replace it with this clause

```
invert(Exp, ILeft-IRight):-
  Exp=..[+, Left, Right],
  !,
  invert(Left, ILeft),
  invert(Right, IRight).
```

Comment: `IExp=..[-,ILeft, IRight]` can be safely replaced by `IExp = ILeft-IRight`

Comment: Right!, i've simplified the first clause. The one that benefits from univ was really the second clause.

Comment: but, now you no longer profit from the instantiation errror.  That is, `invert(X, Y)` now loops, anyway not the worst behaviour.

Comment: Right, I've edited the answer to show how to avoid this, although i guess OP did not intent to use `invert/2` with both arguments uninstantiated.

Comment: Keeping predicates robust w.r.t. instantiations means more robust code.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something a lot simplier:

```
invert(P,P):-atomic(P). % P is konstant, e.g. invert(3,3)->true
invert(T-P,T1-P1):-invert(P,P1),invert(T,T1).
invert(T+P,T1-P1):-invert(P,P1),invert(T,T1).
```

Comment: This is less general, it won't work with e.g. `invert(1+2*3, X)`.

Comment: Agreed. Depends on what can appear in the first argument - I expected + and - operations, however adding anything else wouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: `invert(X,Y)` fails, but `X = a, invert(X, Y)` succeeds. So this is no longer a relation. +1 for the courage!